# Hide Horizon Line with Small Terrain?

Tags: 3d, graphics, fragment-shader

I'm drawing a sky plane with an atmosphere fragment shader in front of my terrain. It looks pretty much fine at sea level, but if you move above the sea level, the illusion is quickly broken, as you can see from the image.

Looks fine:
[image]

Illusion is broken as you move higher up:
[image]

I've googled this, and either I've heard either 1. you can make the render distance really large to compensate for this which is not an option, or 2. mix the fog colors with the sky plane colors, which also does not work, because my sky plane is not a single color and mixing fog with the color below the horizon line wouldn't look good or make sense.

Is there any way to get around this? Can fog even be used here to cover the horizon line? Or am I forced to resort to a solid color sky plane, or at least one that doesn't have a horizon line?

Comment: By the looks of it, you're making some kind of Minecraft clone, in that case, why would you ever see the skybox below you. In Minecraft, chunks are constantly loaded so that you cant see down that far. When you actually break through the bottom of the world, you can in fact see that it's black and doesn't have a skybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any sky whatsoever will look wrong when you are far above a tiny level and can see the level clearly sitting in empty space below you. The difference between a smooth background and complex geometry is immediately obvious to the eye. You'll never be able to make the perspective in your second picture look *good*, especially in motion. To avoid this problem, pick a solution:

- Don't let the player fly that high.
- Choose your “fog” to be strong enough that by the time you can easily see the edges of the world below you, it's thoroughly fogged out. That is, if your level geometry is small, make the fog close to match it.

---

But we can do the sky better too.

It looks to me like you're calculating a simulated  atmosphere, but not accounting for what's *behind* that atmosphere. Abstractly, pixels below the horizon should not just be colored by the atmosphere, but also colored by the ground that they strike after passing through the atmosphere. Of course, you don't want to have infinitely large geometry, but you can pick an average color for your distant ground, and use that in your sky calculation. Here's what that looks like, using an extremely simple sky (no atmospheric simulation, just an upper and lower color) I happen to have recently programmed:

[image: sky at edge of geometry]

Now, obviously there is an edge to the geometry here. But it blends into the sky visually, because the lower half of the sky is calculated as equal to the color of the grass lit by the color of the upper half of the sky. Thus, the bottom half *looks like* an infinite plane similar to the ground plane in the foreground.

If you are simulating a spherical world (or, in general, finite size rather than an infinite plane), then the horizon line below which the ground is visible should naturally move down as the viewpoint moves higher up. This is fine — everything works out as long as the actual level geometry doesn't end up sticking up *above* the portion of the sky rendering that is ground-colored, which should always be true if your calculations are physically-based. Here's an exaggerated diagram of how that should work out (presented as a 2D slice through the 3D space that passes through the viewpoint):

[image: Diagram of viewing angles]

You probably still won't want the player to actually fly this high, so the angles will be smaller.

> or 2. mix the fog colors with the sky plane colors, which also does not work, because my sky plane is not a single color and mixing fog with the color below the horizon line wouldn't look good or make sense.

What is fog?

- Physically, fog is just the part of the atmosphere between you and objects. It's not different from what's happening in the sky.
- In rendering, fog is how we make very different stuff gradually fade out rather than being abruptly cut off.

**You can and should make your “fog color” be the sky color**. Render your sky to a texture, then when drawing your geometry, in the fragment shader, sample the texture and use that as the fog color. This will make distant objects fade into matching the sky (at any angle), and thus be completely invisible once they are finally clipped. If you use any other color, there will be visible clipping.